# No map received warning when launching nav2 with rviz2 using custom robot simulation on gazebo

Tags: ros2, gazebo-simu, rviz

#### System Specification

```
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
ROS2-HUMBLE
Gazebo11
```

So basically, I am using gazebo to simulate an environment for my robot to map. Mapping using slam and nav2 works perfectly. However, when I want to launch the nav2 and rviz2 with the map that I had saved, the map does not load on rviz2
[rviz visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENgtH.png)
The launch file is as follows:

```py
import os
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, PathJoinSubstitution
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare
from launch_ros.actions import Node

MAP_NAME='playground' #change to the name of your own map here

def generate_launch_description():
    depth_sensor = os.getenv('LINOROBOT2_DEPTH_SENSOR', '')

    nav2_launch_path = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [FindPackageShare('nav2_bringup'), 'launch', 'bringup_launch.py']
    )

    rviz_config_path = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [FindPackageShare('linorobot2_navigation'), 'rviz', 'linorobot2_navigation.rviz']
    )

    default_map_path = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [FindPackageShare('linorobot2_navigation'), 'maps', f'{MAP_NAME}.yaml']
    )

    nav2_config_path = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [FindPackageShare('linorobot2_navigation'), 'config', 'navigation.yaml']
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            name='sim', 
            default_value='false',
            description='Enable use_sime_time to true'
        ),

        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            name='rviz', 
            default_value='false',
            description='Run rviz'
        ),

       DeclareLaunchArgument(
            name='map', 
            default_value=default_map_path,
            description='Navigation map path'
        ),

        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(nav2_launch_path),
            launch_arguments={
                'map': LaunchConfiguration("map"),
                'use_sim_time': LaunchConfiguration("sim"),
                'params_file': nav2_config_path
            }.items()
        ),

        Node(
            package='rviz2',
            executable='rviz2',
            name='rviz2',
            output='screen',
            arguments=['-d', rviz_config_path],
            condition=IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration("rviz")),
            parameters=[{'use_sim_time': LaunchConfiguration("sim")}]
        )
    ])
```

#### To reproduce the problem simply,

```
mkdir ws
cd ws
mkdir src
git clone -b humble https://github.com/linorobot/linorobot2 src/linorobot2
git clone https://github.com/linorobot/linorobot2_viz src/linorobot2_viz
rosdep update && rosdep install --from-path src --ignore-src -y 
colcon build
```

In one terminal run

```
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
source install/setup.bash
ros2 launch linorobot2_gazebo gazebo.launch.py
```

Open another terminal

```
cd ws
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
source install/setup.bash
ros2 launch linorobot2_navigation navigation.launch.py sim:=true rviz:=true
```

rviz will then show this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lbQX.png)
I have tried the nav2 turtlebot3 tutorial and their map shows up fine on rviz which indicates it's neither a gazebo nor rviz2 issue. I checked our topic list and found /map, /map_server/transition_event, /map_updates are present.
I also cross-compared our launch file, robot_model file, and maps files with turtlebot3 but is unable to identify any part that is wrong. Does anyone have an idea about why the map is not received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,I managed to solved this problem.

In this specific case, there is nothing wrong with the map publisher or the launch file. The problem lies with the **amcl**. Just make the following changes to the navigation.yaml file in the config folder,

```
robot_model_type: "differential"
```

to

```
robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
```

Rebuild the workspace and it should works.

To add on, I also found out that the PC I am using is being bottlenecked which also cause the localization to not work properly. So just ensure the cpu/gpu is powerful enough

Answer (score 0):

Does this problem occur when you switch to real robot? It works with gazebo simulated linorobot, but map still does not load when running nav2 on real robot after mapping with slam.

This may be an issue with real robot using micro ros for communication with the firmware. I tried running cyclone DDS but that is not compatible with micro ros.

Comment: This is more of a clarifying question than an answer. Those could be left as comments to the original question rather than as an answer.